# Java Hadoop Gengerate no result

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have made a test with Hadoop Map and Reducer with code below:
App.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Words Count Start!");
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/Users/xx/Meekou/Meekou.hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2.tar/hadoop-3.2.2");
        URL url = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("wordcount.txt");
        Path inputPath = new Path(URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(),"UTF-8") );
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "WordsCount");
        job.setJarByClass(App.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordsCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordsCountReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("./result.txt"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Words Count Complete!");
    }
```

WordsCountMapper.java

```
public class WordsCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(WordsCountMapper.class);
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        LOG.info(line);
        String[] words = line.split(",");
        for (String word : words) {
            LOG.info(word);
            context.write(new Text(word), one);
        }      
        // StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        // while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //     word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        //     context.write(word, one);
        // }  
    }
}
```

WordsCountReducer.java

```
public class WordsCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> words,
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int frequencyForWord = 0;
        for(IntWritable word: words){
            frequencyForWord += word.get();
        }
        System.out.println(key);
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(frequencyForWord));
    }
}
```

And test txt file content is

```
tom,jack,mary,
rose,anly,billo,anly,
billo,mary,zoor,
zoor,poly,
```

It generated empty `result` folder instead of expected result.

Comment: it's so strange, the `job.waitForCompletion(true)` return false, but there is no any error. In addition, I have another hdfs project, it works. I assume this is not replated with environment.